# Run a Crystal report from C# passing parameters without using a Viewer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am writing a "proof-of-concept" console app to test calling and retrieving Crystal Reports. I don't want to use a ReportViewer and instead what to retrieve reports via a stream. I am using the CRforVS redist libraries CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine and CrystalDecisions.Shared. My code is shown below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = new ReportDocument();
    x.Load("[REPORT PATH]");
    x.SetParameterValue("[PARAM NAME]", "[PARAM VALUE]");
    // set parameter values

    SetDbLoginForReport(x);

    Sections sections = x.ReportDefinition.Sections;
    foreach (Section section in sections)
    {
        ReportObjects reportObjects = section.ReportObjects;
        foreach (ReportObject reportObject in reportObjects)
        {
            if (reportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
            {
                SubreportObject subreportObject = (SubreportObject)reportObject;
                ReportDocument subReportDocument = subreportObject.OpenSubreport(subreportObject.SubreportName);
                SetDbLoginForReport(subReportDocument);
            }
        }
    }

    var s = x.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.CrystalReport);

}

private static void SetDbLoginForReport(ReportDocument document)
{
    foreach (var table in document.Database.Tables)
    {
        var conn = new ConnectionInfo();
        var myTable = table as Table;
        var myTableLogonInfo = myTable.LogOnInfo;
        conn.ServerName = "";
        conn.DatabaseName = "";
        conn.UserID = "";
        conn.Password = "";
        myTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = conn;
        myTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(myTableLogonInfo);
    }
}
```

ExportToStream gives an error with a message of "Failed to Open Connection." and throws the following exception:

```
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportOptions options)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType formatType)
   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\paul.welbourne\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 41
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I am not setting any DataSources as they are already set-up in Crystal Report. Also, I am sure my connection strings are correct as I can connect to the data source's database with them. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this issue. I had to create an System DNS in Programs -> Administrative Tools -> ODBC DataSources for the Database connection for the report.

Comment: Please Can you tell me what all options did you configure?